# .net core signalr to mvc signalr

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, signalr

Hello im trying to migrate a project from .net core to mvc and i have some issues about signalr.

This work on new mvc project.

```
Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
// Start the connection.
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    alert("done");
});
```

But this one which is from the old(.net core) project doesnt work.
Error is : **Uncaught ReferenceError: signalR is not defined**

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

connection.start().then(function () {
    console.log('SignalR Started...');
    viewModel.roomList();
    viewModel.userList();
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (viewModel.chatRooms().length > 0) {
            viewModel.joinRoom(viewModel.chatRooms()[0]);
        }
    }, 250);
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error("!!!!!" + err);
});
```

[image]

browser/signalr.js the first one define signalR but this time the error is : Error: **Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error**

Comment: Error message is quite clear. You need to define `signalR` above `var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();` line of yours

Comment: @RaZzLe Firstly i think the signalR work different on mvc. The signalR defined in browser/signalr.js but this time error message about negotiation.

Comment: This could be anything.. Maybe you forgot to migrate something from your old .net core project's appsettings.json file (regarding this server definition) or the server you are trying to connect is simply down.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was in my constructor method. I could not trigger server side methods. My old project want initialize variables and there was no try catch block. So i deleted constructor method. Then it worked.